# howto sort a asp:Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible to simply sort a asp:Table by columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YourTableName.DefaultView.Sort = "YourColumnName ASC";
YourTableName.DefaultView.Sort = "YourColumnName DESC";
```

Comment: i have a asp:table and not a dataTable :(

Comment: i don't know ,but you can use another control or map the data to datatable , sorting it then bind on the table.i don't know if there is some way in LINQ.